# UserCustomAction does not fire for non-tenant admin in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have written a fairly straight-forward JavaScript for SharePoint Online that I am deploying as a user custom action into the root site collection using CSOM.

The following code is the block I am using for provisioning the script to the site collection:

```
public static void ProvisionScriptLinkCustomAction(ClientContext ctx, string name, string url)
    {
        Site site = ctx.Site;
        ctx.Load(site.UserCustomActions);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (UserCustomAction action in site.UserCustomActions)
        {
            if (action.Name == name)
            {
                action.DeleteObject();
                break;
            }
        }
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        UserCustomAction customAction = site.UserCustomActions.Add();
        customAction.Location = "ScriptLink";
        customAction.Name = name;
        customAction.ScriptSrc = url + "?" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        customAction.Update();

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

I am logged in as the tenant administrator when deploying and initially testing the custom action.  Everything works as expected until I log in as a user that is **not** the tenant admin.  When logged in as any other user that is only a site collection administrator or lower, the custom action does not fire and all of my efforts are for naught.

This feels like a configuration or permissions issue to me but I am at a loss to begin to know where to look to rectify this issue.

Any helpful thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Despite clearing browser cache, logging in with multiple browsers and all the other tricks for dealing with potential cache issues, I thought this had boiled down to a cache issue.  I turned on the network analyzer in IE developer tools while hitting my site and could see the JS file loading.  As soon as I saw it load, the expected behavior (popping external links in a new tab or window) manifested itself.  However, if I went back to the site without developer tools running, the script would not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had console.log calls in my JavaScript.  Some versions of IE apparently do not know how to log to the console when in browser mode without debug tools which presumably throws an uncaught and unlogged exception.  Removing the console.log statements made the issue go away.